# asp.net core 2 web api task run background task

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am now working a application . my requirement is i want to insert data in elasticsearch without wait in controller . This insert process run in another background thread without waiting in controller . Controller call this tread before return and without waiting for this process response user data.

Anyone tell me the process how can i manage this architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question far too broad, but generally speaking, you need some sort of background process and a way to schedule work on that. In that regard, there's literally a myriad of options, but they fall into one of these three main buckets:

1. `IHostedService` in ASP.NET Core. There's [sample code for a queue-based hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks) that would likely meet your needs. This is probably the simplest way to get going, but also the least robust. In particular, if your application stops, the queue will go with it, potentially resulting in lost items.
2. A third-party tool like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). This is a good middle-of-the-road approach. Relatively easy to set up and relatively resilient.
3. A message queue, like RabbitMQ. Essentially, you send a message to the queue, and then you have "subscribers" that listen on that queue for particular message types and take actions based on that. This is a little more complicated to set up, but also much more resilient than other approaches. There's ways to ensure message delivery, even when there's failures, and you can actually have multiple workers to round-robin the queue for scale.